# Add Extra Image Dimension in FLUTTER

Tags: flutter, tensorflow, dart

I want to convert an image shape from (c, w, h) to (b,c,w,h) i.e I need to add an extra dimension to an image (1,224,224,3).

I need this because I am working with tensorflow tflite model in FLUTTER. My model accepts a 4 dimensional tensor. I am not sure how to expand dimension in FLUTTER.

Comment: Hi! You can use ML kit model binding to change input and output shape desired requirement for your need. Attached relevant [thread](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/use-custom-models#:~:text=FirebaseModelInputOutputOptions%20inputOutputOptions%20%3D,.build()%3B) for reference.